# Problems to install Magento on AWS

Tags: magento2, file-permissions, magento-community, aws

I'm trying to install **Magento CE** 2 on **AWS** following this tutorial:

https://comtechies.com/how-to-install-magento-on-amazon-ec2.html

However, I cannot go to http:///magento. I've look on Google and I saw that my /app/etc/env.php does not exist.

How should I proceed to finish this installation?

Many thanks!

Comment: what is en error. Please check log files. It might be permission issue for var and pub folder.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your root directory and run this command. Replace your db credentials and base url.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```